# Error handling to call a supplementary observable (to fix the error) with RxJava

Tags: java, system.reactive, rx-java, observable

I have created an interface that contains three methods that return observables. They:

1. query a REST API to get a list of articles
2. save a list of articles to a local database
3. retrieve all my articles from the local database

However, if method #3 is called before #2, it would return an empty list, where size of the list of articles returned is 0. So then I want to retrieve a fresh list of articles from a REST API. Here's the pseudo-code of the observable chain I want to create.

1. Call `getAllArticles()`
2. if (error occurs, or `getAllArticles().size()` == 0) then `refreshArticles()` (only let this be called once),
3. call `getAllArticles()` again

I am designing this observable chain so any of the 3 methods can be called in any order, and still function as expected. I have the following interface:

```
/**
 * A repository abstraction in charge of handling all our data needs related to articles.
 */
public interface ArticleRepo {
    /**
     * Gets all the articles stored in the database
     *
     * @return An observable containing a list of articles
     */
    public Observable<List<ArticleEntity>> getAllArticles();


    /**
     * Refreshes the currently stored article repos, and returns
     * @return an updated {@link ArticleRepo}
     */
    public Observable<ArticleRepo> refreshArticles();

    /**
     * Saves the list of article entities to the database
     * @param articleEntityList
     * @return
     */
    Observable<List<ArticleEntity>> save(List<ArticleEntity> articleEntityList);

}
```

How do I implement a type of error handling, so that `refreshArticles()`/`saveArticles()` is automatically called when `getAllArticles()` is not able to return the correct data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I implement a type of error handling, so that refreshArticles()/saveArticles() is automatically called when getAllArticles() is not able to return the correct data?

I think [`onErrorResumeNext`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#onErrorResumeNext(rx.Observable)) and [`switchIfEmpty`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#switchIfEmpty(rx.Observable)) operator will be really helpful in your case. Here is an example of how your flow can be implemented in `rx-java` using these operators:

```
final ArticleRepo repository = getCurrentArticleRepo();

final Observable<List<ArticleEntity>> refresh = repository.refreshArticles().flatMap(new Func1<ArticleRepo, Observable<List<ArticleEntity>>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<List<ArticleEntity>> call(final ArticleRepo updated) {
        return updated.getAllArticles();
    }
}).flatMap(new Func1<List<ArticleEntity>, Observable<List<ArticleEntity>>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<List<ArticleEntity>> call(final List<ArticleEntity> articles) {
        return repository.save(articles);
    }
});

repository.getAllArticles().onErrorResumeNext(refresh).filter(new Func1<List<ArticleEntity>, Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call(final List<ArticleEntity> articles) {
        return articles == null || articles.size() == 0;
    }
}).switchIfEmpty(refresh).subscribe(new Action1<List<ArticleEntity>>() {
    @Override
    public void call(final List<ArticleEntity> articles) {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

PS: I'm not sure if `refresh` observable implemented correctly because I don't really understand when I need to call `save` method.

Comment: yeah, my API should be more clear. `refresh` pulls the new data without saving it - and `save` commits it to a database.

`getAllArticles` gets the articles from local storage, and refreshes/saves the data if necessary.

So if `getAllArticles` is the very first thing called, then `refresh` and `save` are called as well

Comment: I would also say the `save` method has no purpose being the the public API, as every `refresh` will be saving the data.

Comment: The way articles being saved actually is not so important here. The interesting part starts from `onErrorResumeNext` call.